# How can I tell how many data tracks are on a CD?

Tags: compact-disc

I know data CDs can have multiple tracks as a result of adding/deleting or modifying files in additions burns to the disk. (I guess they aren't track but rather sessions or some such thing?)

I need to know how many there are (well really I need to make sure there is only one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com) has a verify option, which allows you to read this information:

[image]